# How to Correctly Show a Component Based on State in React

Tags: reactjs, async-await, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I have an async function that finds out whether a user has voted by making a call to Mongo. If they have voted I would like to display one component (Results component), if they haven't I would like to display a different component (Questions component). However, whatever I do, it *always* displays a flash of the Questions component before changing to the Results component if they have voted. It's driving me crazy and I've spent hours on it trying every possible permutation.

My function which establishes whether they have voted or not is:

```
const [hasVoted, setHasVoted] = useState(false)
const [gotUserData, setGotUserData] = useState(false)

useEffect(() => {
    async function findHasVoted() {
        let response = await axios.get(`/api/polls/get-user-vote?userId=${userId}&postId=${postId}`)
        if (response.data.userId===userId) {
            setHasVoted(true)  
        }
        setGotUserData(true)
    }
    findHasVoted()
},[userId, postId])
```

For simplicity's sake the JSX is as follows. If we have got the user data (gotUserData===true) and they have voted (hasVoted===true) show results, otherwise if we've got the user data and they haven't voted, show the questions:

```
{gotUserData===true && hasVoted===true ? <span>RESULTS</span>:null}
{gotUserData===true && hasVoted===false ? <span>QUESTIONS</span>:null}
```

How can I code it so that I don't get the flash of the Questions component if the user has voted?

I can't just do the following as 'hasVoted' is set to false by default.

```
{hasVoted===true ? <span>RESULTS</span>:null}
{hasVoted===false ? <span>QUESTIONS</span>:null}
```

To get around any falsy issues I have tried not using boolean values for hasVoted:

```
const [hasVoted, setHasVoted] = useState('xx')
```

And then in the findHasVoted() function:

```
if (response.data.userId===userId) {
    setHasVoted('yes')  
} else {
    setHasVoted('no')
)
setGotUserData(true)
```

And in the JSX

```
{gotUserData===true && hasVoted==='yes' ? <span>RESULTS</span>:null}
{gotUserData===true && hasVoted==='no' ? <span>QUESTIONS</span>:null}
```

But it still flashes Questions before showing Results when the user has voted, which I can't understand as I'm now explicitly specifying 'yes' or 'no' and the default value is 'xx'. I'm sure it's a fairly simple issue, but one for which I cannot find the answer.

Any help very, very much appreciated.

Comment: Try to avoid ternary operator if it helps:`{gotUserData ===true && hasVoted==='no' && <span>QUESTIONS</span>}` and its more readable in my opinion :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider reducing the amount of `useStates`. that way you can better keep track of your data and debug your issue. In your useEffect, you can set the data you receive from your axios method and use that to render your component.

Now all you have to do is check the value of `userHasVoted`. On the first render that value is `undefined`. After the axios method its either `true` or `false`.

```
const [userHasVoted, setUserHasVoted] = useState(undefined);


useEffect(() => {
    async function findHasVoted() {
        let response = await axios.get(`/api/polls/get-user-vote?userId=${userId}&postId=${postId}`)
        // check if user has voted  
        const hasVoted = response.data?.userId === userId ? true : false;
        setUserHasVoted(hasVoted);
    }
    findHasVoted();
},[userId, postId])

console.log(userHasVoted); // either undefined, true or false

return (
    <>
        {userHasVoted === true && <p>Answer: {yourAnswer}</p>}
        {userHasVoted === false && <p>Question: {yourQuestion}</p>} 
        // For illustration purposes:
        {userHasVoted === undefined && <p>Loading...</p>}
    </>
)
```

Comment: Thank for your answer j-low. I'm still having the same issue. Using your method, if the user has voted votingData is an object containing a userId, which is fine. If the user hasn't voted, votingData is undefined. So even if I change the second condition to {votingData===undefined && <p>QUESTION</p>} the question will still show for a brief period for someone who has voted before votingData gets assigned the object

Comment: When does your `useEffect` run? Should it run on first render to fetch the data or is triggered after the user does something in the UI?

Comment: My understanding is that you don't want to show any question or answer until you know if the user has voted. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, correct. The useEffect should run when it has the userId and the postId, in the dependencies array. I think I'm asking the wrong question here to be honest. After lots of console logging and playing around, it's apparent because the function in the useEffect is async, hasVoted will always be falsy at some stage, which is causing the flash of questions for polls which have already been answered.

Comment: You're right about your conclusion and you can use this to your advantage. Please note that in my example I'm checking  `votingData && !votingData.userId === userId` so it checks if it has `votingData` and only then checks for the second statement. In my example, when `votingData === undefined`, none of the UI should show.

Comment: An alternative way of writing that statement could be: 
`{votingData && ( <> {votingData.userId === userId && <p>Answer: {yourAnswer}</p>} {votingData.userId !== userId && <p>Question: {yourQuestion}</p>} </> )}`

Comment: I've updated the example to use the alternative way of writing the statement. It might be more clear that way :)

Comment: Thanks j-low - it doesn't work because where a user hasn't voted, votingData is undefined, and therefore the questions won't be shown

Comment: Gotcha! I understand now. there are 3 states. 1: request is pending and neither answer nor question should show. 2: Question is answered and answer should show. 3: Question is not answered and question should show. I've updated the example, and hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: One improvement would be replacing `undefined` with `null` as this is more explicit as an empty value.

Comment: @RayPurchase, has the updated answer been helpful for you?